# Python variable length generics types

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-typing

Is is possible to create a generic type that access a variable length argument types?

Basically, I'm trying to create a generic observable where the user can define which arguments they want to accept with type hints.

Ex:

```
Types = TypeVar("Types", var_length=True)

class Obserable(Generic[Types]):

    def subscribe(func: Callable[[Types], None]):
        ...

    def notify(*args: Types):
        ...

def callback(arg1: int, arg2: str, arg3: int) -> None:
    ...

observer: Observable[int, str, int] = Observable()
observer.subscribe(callback)
observer.notify(1, "hello", 5)
```

Answer (score 8):

Note: This feature was [added in Python 3.11](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.11.html#pep-646-variadic-generics)

---

As far as I know, [no](https://github.com/python/typing/issues/193). [But they plan to add it](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0646/) and [is working on it](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/24527).

To quote:

> PEP 484 introduced TypeVar, enabling creation of generics parameterised with a single type. In this PEP, we introduce TypeVarTuple, enabling parameterisation with an arbitrary number of types - that is, a variadic type variable, enabling variadic generics. This enables a wide variety of use cases. In particular, it allows the type of array-like structures in numerical computing libraries such as NumPy and TensorFlow to be parameterised with the array shape, enabling static type checkers to catch shape-related bugs in code that uses these libraries.

Comment: This has been accepted as [PEP646](https://peps.python.org/pep-0646/) and scheduled for Python 3.11. For < 3.11 the [`typing_extensions` package](https://pypi.org/project/typing-extensions/) provides backports. So the TypeVarTuple feature is available right now.